# Solr : SolrQueryResponse

Tags: java, solr

Well I have seen a lot people adding results to SolrQueryResponse object using 
rsp.add("response",result). Here 'rsp' is SolrQueryResponse object , "response" is string (obviously) , result is SolrDocumentList.

My confusion is I am not able to understand how do we get to know that we have to use string "response" to send response to client.

I have read SolrQueryResponse class but didn't find anything.

Any help

Comment: what programming language are you using, PHP?

Comment: Dude , No No .. I am not using PHP. Actaully I am writing custom request handler using solr apis . While googling I found at many places they have used rsp.add("response",result); .. you can look at this link http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html